# hover эффект при наведении на блок

Tags: html, css

Уже который день питаюсь сверстать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл в пом, что при наведении на заголовок должна появляться рамка, дополнительный текст и кнопка.

Сделал 4 блока:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="advantages one"></section>
    <section class="advantages two"></section>
    <section class="advantages three"></section>
    <section class="advantages four"></section>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container::before,
.container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.container::after {
    clear: both;
}

.advantages {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50vh;
}

.advantages.one {
    background-image: url(/img/1.jpg);
}

.advantages.two {
    background-image: url(/img/2.jpg);
}

.advantages.three {
    background-image: url(/img/3.jpg);
}

.advantages.four {
    background-image: url(/img/4.jpg);
}
```

И на этом все. Как я только не про бывал крутить. Может кто-то дать малейшую наводку по реализации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример

```css
.advantages {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/250x250/999999/999999);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.advantages:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.advantages:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.advantages-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.advantages:hover:before,
.advantages:hover:after,
.advantages:hover .advantages-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantages">
  <div class="advantages-text">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <a href="#">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: еще бы как-то добавить background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); на весь блок

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вроде так

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="overlay">
    этот блок появится
  </div>
</div>
```